# jquery serialize multiple checkboxes with same name

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization, checkbox

I have searched and searched but cannot find answer to fit my exact situation. I am hoping someone can help.

I am trying to "retrofit" a site using frames to use ajax and divs now. All is going well, except...

This site has multiple forms. I am trying to write jquery code to handle all forms (using ajax of course). Therefore, using id selectors and the like is out. The real problem comes in when using `serialize()` to handle multiple checkboxes with same name.

Consider the following scenario:

HTML

```
<form name="theform" method="post" action="form.cgi">
<input type="hidden" name="directory" value="test">
<input type="checkbox" name="file" value="file1.txt">
<input type="checkbox" name="file" value="file2.txt">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="file" value="file10.txt">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(':submit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//Serialize form data from the parent form of the clicked submit button
//This will enable handling of all forms across the site
var formData=$(this.form).serialize();
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "form.cgi", data: formData, cache: false, 
contentType: false, processData: false, success:function({alert(formData);}});
});
```

This results in the alert showing only the `directory` field and corresponding value. None of the checkboxes (checked checkboxes, that is) are showing up in the data string.

Why is `serialize()` not handling the checkboxes? I have read cases of cycling through the checkboxes, but I am not sure if this is possible. Also keep in mind that the processing script uses data in format of `name=value` so data fed in should look like `file=file1.txt&file=file2.txt&file=file3.txt`.

Hope someone can help me with this...this one's got me befuddled.

Comment: use `name='file[]'`?

Comment: It is working as expected here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/o6jaexws/

Comment: Problem is since you are having multiple forms

Comment: What do you mean "multiple forms"? I checked  your fiddle, and yes it is true that it does indeed work, yet I cannot get it do replicate those results in the native environment.

Comment: Would the fact that the various fields (checkboxes, inputs, etc.) are broken up by different `table` elements affect this at all?

Comment: It would seem that it does......????? Ideas how to work around this?